# why bundler is populating ./libv8 not into the rvm folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

I am using ubuntu and rvm 1.8.6, ruby 1.9.2, bundler (1.1.rc, 1.0.21), it was working ok. But recently, I cleared my gemset and run `bundle install` again to get freshen up because some stupid things I did on my own.

But the bundler puts all the gems under ./libv8 folder inside my project folder, it's quite weird to me. And my rvm folder is getting nothing. Is it because of the "therubyracer"? The following is my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rake', '>=0.9.2'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem 'gdata'
#gem 'SystemTimer', '1.2.3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `.bundle/config` file in your app's root.

Check if the `BUNDLE_PATH` variable is set, and in case it is, delete it.

Bundler will go back to `rubygem`'s default behaviour, which is installing gems in `$GEM_HOME`.

You probably executed `bundle install --path ./libv8` once and forgot about it.

Comment: I think you are probably right, that day I deleted the project folder and cloned it again, then everything is all right. So, I think you are correct about that.